# Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem with two different eigenfunctions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I am trying to express a function $f(x)$ in terms of a complete set of eigenfunctions found from a Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem:

$$2y''(x)+4y'(x)+\lambda y(x)=0$$
$$y(0)=0, y'(2)=0$$

For this i found that when $\lambda =2+2\beta^2$ i get the eigenfunction $y_n=e^{-x}\sin(\beta_n x)$ and when $\lambda=2-\beta^2$, $y_n=e^{-x}\sinh(\beta_n x)$.

Normally to express $f(x)$ in terms of the eigenfunctions i use:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n y_n(x), a<x<b$$
where,
$$C_n=\frac{I_1}{I_2}$$
and,
$$I_1=\int_a^b r(x)f(x)y_n(x)dx$$
$$I_2=\int_a^b r(x)y_n^2(x)dx$$

But as i have different sets of eigenfunctions depending on my $\lambda$, which should i use for my $y_n(x)$?

Comment: What is $y(0)$ equal to ?

Comment: $0$ sorry. edited